# Trouble thawing data structures stored with Storable::nfreeze?

Tags: perl, storable

I have a bunch of data stored in a single column in a MySQL table.  I have access to the ~5 year old perl code which stored it there & can see that it is all hashes which were frozen with `Storable::nfreeze` before being stored.  The MySQL column is `TEXT` and the table is set to `latin1` encoding.  I'm now trying to retrieve this data back out for a one-off export.  I know the app was originally running on perl 5.8.x, so I'm attempting this with perl-5.8.8.  Unfortunately, I don't know what version of Storable was used.

I first attempted using the most recent Storable, 2.39.  That gives me:

```
Storable binary image v32.32 more recent than I am (v2.9) at
perlbrew/perls/perl-5.8.8/lib/5.8.8/darwin-2level/Storable.pm line 417`
```

With Storable-2.14 I get

```
Storable binary image v32.32 more recent than I am (v2.7) at blib/lib/Storable.pm
(autosplit into blib/lib/auto/Storable/thaw.al) line 363
```

With Storable-2.13 I get

```
Storable binary image v2.7 more recent than I am (v2.6) at blib/lib/Storable.pm  
(autosplit into blib/lib/auto/Storable/thaw.al) line 363
```

The unreasonably high binary image numbers in >= 2.14 make me think there's some change with how the numbers are being parsed.  I believe this code was probably running on a 32bit OS, and now I'm trying this on a 64bit machine, could that be relavant?  Next up is I'm going to attempt running a diff between 2.13 & 2.14 to see if I can figure out what's causing the change.

Any guidance anyone can give?

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect the 32bit / 64bit issue may indeed be relevant. Try running it on a 32-bit version of perl and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Format 2.7 was first used with Storable 2.14.

The size of the your Perl's integers (not the size of your machine's integers) would indeed cause the inability to parse the data.

Comment: Thanks! How do I configure perl's integer size when compiling?

Comment: `-Duse64bitint` for 64, but can't force 32. There could be other differences that matter too. Stored data is not really meant to be shared between Perl builds.

Comment: Is there any way figure out from the stored data what perl configurations it would need to be read?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it turns out I needed to decode the value before I could thaw it. So,

```
use Storable qw( thaw );
use MIME::Base64 qw( decode_base64 );
my $data = thaw( decode_base64( $frozen_thing ) );
```

In my case the data had been stored using Apache::Session::Serialize::Base64.  I had assumed it had been stored using Apache::Session::Serialize::Storable, hence the problem.  In this case, the error message is a red herring, but at least you know *something* is wrong.